# Chaos testing of Vertx Application

Tags: vert.x, chaos, vertx-httpclient, vertx-eventbus, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

Pointers on any tool for chaos testing of Vertx application deployed on Openshift. Will chaos monkey work or any other tool out there?

Comment: We do not test chaos monkey for spring boot against vertx applications. You can of course give it a try. There is still a bug open, which makes its use problematic with an underlying netty.

Answer (score 0):

On a local installation of OpenShift (minishift or all on a single machine) Pumba https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba does work well as it can connect to the local docker socket and kill pods.

Only be careful to exclude the OC pods otherwise sudenly the UI will also stop working too.

If you would like to know more about openshift + pumba, please check this slide deck I wrote last year: https://www.jetdrone.xyz/presentations/codemotion-amsterdam-2018/

Comment: Thanks Paulo. Any tools for load testing on vertx application?

Comment: On the presentation I've shown `wrk`, slide https://www.jetdrone.xyz/presentations/codemotion-amsterdam-2018/#/20 link here: https://github.com/wg/wrk

Comment: Thanks Paulo. Want to perform chaos testing of a Vertx application which reads data from multiple sources like Kafka/Database. The application is hosted on Openshift. Is Chaos monkey supported for Vertx applications? I could not find the maven plugin for Vertx. All the support currently looks to be for Spring boot i guess. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vertx is an officially supported runtime on openshift. Vertx however doesn't require any specific plug-in, the standard fabric8 plug-in will do.